# Why am I getting an eye symbol on my mail accounts at password fields on Internet Explorer?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Windows 7, from today I am getting an eye symbol on my password field and a "X" symbol on username field. This only happens in Internet Explorer, and not in Google Chrome.

I am scared my email and computer might have been hacked. What should I do to disable this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have been updated to Internet Explorer 10. The eye symbol allows you to check the password you have entered and the X on the User Name allows you to quickly delete what has been entered and start again.